# Mobile phone protocols

Tags: mobile, protocols

What are the different protocols available for communicating between web and a mobile phone?

Comment: Question is extremely vague. There are at least several 10's of such protocols, and giving a helpful answer really requires some idea of why the question is being asked.

... and it's not really programming related, as Paul R says.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [SMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_message_peer-to-peer_protocol) used to communicate with a [Short message service center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_message_service_center) via an application.

EDIT: This assumes you mean communicate via SMS.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of the obvious... HTTP? :)